# I am trying to get top5 products from a list of products

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

So i have a data like this

| Category | subcategory | crn | product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 | product5 | product6 | product7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | Y | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| A | Z | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | X 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |

And i want to showcase output like this

| Category | subcategory | crncount | topproduct1 | topproduct2 | topproduct3 | topproduct4 | topproduct5 | sumofproduct1 | sumof product2 | sumofprduct3 | sumofproduct4 | sumofprodct5 | sumofproduct6 | sumofprodct7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 1 | product3 | product2 | product4 | product5 | product6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | y | 1 | product3 | product4 | product5 | product6 | product7 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | x | 1 | product1 | product3 | product4 | product5 | product6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | y | 1 | product3 | product2 | product4 | product5 | product6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have tried this code
df.groupby([category, subcategory)]
group.agg({crn: count, product1:sum, product2:sum, product3:sum......)

Topproduct = df.iloc[:,1:].sum().nlargest(5).index.tolist()

Comment: "and vote for it" lol your post doesn't even answer his question..

Comment: are all the values 1? why is product3 the topproduct1 for the first row? where sis the B/Y come from? please make sure your examples are meaningful with non-ambiguous numbers and that the provided output matches the input

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.head.html), and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) back:

```
cols = ['Category', 'subcategory', 'crn']
N = 5

out = (df
   .melt(cols, var_name='topproduct', value_name='sumofproducts')
   .sort_values(by=cols+['sumofproducts'], ascending=False)
   .groupby(cols).head(N)
   .assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby(cols).cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index=cols, columns='col')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}'), axis=1))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Category subcategory  crn topproduct_1 topproduct_2 topproduct_3 topproduct_4 topproduct_5  sumofproducts_1  sumofproducts_2  sumofproducts_3  sumofproducts_4  sumofproducts_5
0        A           X    1     product6     product5     product1     product3     product4                9                7                5                3                3
1        A           Y    1     product6     product7     product4     product5     product1                8                8                7                6                5
2        A           Z    1     product5     product3     product4     product2     product7                8                7                7                6                5
3        B           X    1     product1     product3     product2     product4     product5                9                9                8                4                3
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                   'subcategory': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X'],
                   'crn': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'product1': [5, 5, 1, 9],
                   'product2': [0, 2, 6, 8],
                   'product3': [3, 4, 7, 9],
                   'product4': [3, 7, 7, 4],
                   'product5': [7, 6, 8, 3],
                   'product6': [9, 8, 1, 0],
                   'product7': [3, 8, 5, 3]})
```

Comment: Well, you had the logic the rest is mostly details ;)

Comment: your answer is much nicer - nice one!

Comment: Getting an error values is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument

Comment: @Alok please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that triggers your error

Comment: Issue resolved i more thing i want to showcase the count of crn